# Calculate integral limits for density function?

Tags: probability

Here's a question:

> Let $(X, Y)$ be random variable which uniformly distributes over the triangle $\Delta (0, 0), (1, 1) (2, 0)$.
>
> Find the Y density function.

The solution is :

$ S_{\Delta} = \frac{2}{2} = 1 \text{Then the common density  function} f_{xy} = \frac{1}{S_\Delta} = 1.$

Now in order to find $F_y$ the solution states:

$F_y = \int_y^{2-y} 1dx = 2 -y - y = 2 - 2y$.

Here's a draw of the triangle:

[image]

Can you please explain me how he got this limits?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are "integrating out" $x$.  The left slanted line has equation $y=x$, so for any value of $y$ between $0$ and $1$, $x$ "starts" at $x=y$. The right slanted line has equation $y=2-x$, so $x$ "ends" at $x=2-y$.

Comment: As usual, writing down the PDFs correctly trivializes everything, here the joint PDF $f_{X,Y}$ is defined **on the whole plane** $\mathbb R^2$ by $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=2\,\mathbf 1_{0<y<x<2-y}$$ hence, **for every** $y$ **in** $\mathbb R$, $$f_Y(y)=\int_{\mathbb R}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx=2\,\mathbf 1_{0<y<2}\int_\mathbb R\mathbf 1_{y<x<2-y}dx=\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

On the drawing of the triangle draw a horizontal line through $(0,y)$ with $0<y<1$. This meets the line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ at $x=y$ and the line from $(1,1)$ to $(2,0)$ at $x=2-y$. These are your limits of integration.

Informally this can be explained as: $$Pr\left(Y\in (y,y+\delta y )\right) \approx [(2-y)-y]\delta y=(2-2y)\delta y\approx f(y)\delta y$$

Comment: Pr(Y=y)=0 for **every** y.